# Google GA4 batchRunReports when API doesn't have records throw 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: google-api, google-analytics-4, google-reporting-api

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/rest/v1alpha/TopLevel/batchRunReports

**Request :**

```
{
"entity": {
    "propertyId": "XXXXXXXX"
},
"requests": [
    {
        "entity": {
            "propertyId": "XXXXXXXX"
        },
        "dimensions": [
            {
                "name": "date"
            },
            {
                "name": "dateHour"
            },
            {
                "name": "firstUserCampaignName"
            }
        ],
        "metrics": [
            {
                "name": "sessions"
            }
        ],
        "dateRanges": [
            {
                "startDate": "2021-04-06",
                "endDate": "2021-04-07"
            }
        ],
        "metricAggregations": [
            "TOTAL"
        ],
        "dimensionFilter": {
            "andGroup": {
                "expressions": [
                    {
                        "filter": {
                            "fieldName": "medium",
                            "stringFilter": {
                                "matchType": "EXACT",
                                "value": "Test"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "orderBys": [
            {
                "desc": true,
                "metric": {
                    "metricName": "sessions"
                }
            },
            {
                "desc": false,
                "dimension": {
                    "dimensionName": "dateHour"
                }
            }
        ],
        "keepEmptyRows": true
    }
]
```

}

**Response:**

```
{
"error": {
    "code": 500,
    "message": "Internal error encountered.",
    "status": "INTERNAL"
}
```

}

But if remove following property from request:

```
 "metricAggregations": [
            "TOTAL"
        ],
```

I am able to see following response where there is not rows :

```
{
"reports": [
    {
        "metricHeaders": [
            {
                "name": "sessions",
                "type": "TYPE_INTEGER"
            }
        ],
        "metadata": {},
        "dimensionHeaders": [
            {
                "name": "date"
            },
            {
                "name": "dateHour"
            },
            {
                "name": "firstUserCampaignName"
            }
        ],
        "kind": "analyticsData#runReport"
    }
],
"kind": "analyticsData#batchRunReports"
```

}

Any idea how to prevent 500 internal server error in this case ?

This error block google API call for an hour.

Comment: Your using an Alpha version of an api, you should be expecting to get 500 errors.

Comment: Can you please share any reference link @DaImTo

Comment: I think its your dimensionFilter if you remove that it works.  I am testing with the try me https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/rest/v1alpha/TopLevel/batchRunReports.  Can you verify that Test actually exists as a valid value for medium.  The thing is your not even requesting medium.

Comment: Medium is already working with other values, but it is throwing the error when there is no record match. @DaImTo

Comment: So it works if there is a match but you get 500 if there isn't?

Comment: Yes, it is working, when matching case  @DaImTo

Comment: I am going to ping someone on the team this may qualify as a bug.

Answer (score -1):

Furqan, there seems to be an issue with the Data API where a call using `metricAggregations` is failing in case the generated report is empty. In the meantime, to workaround this error, you can modify a query so that the resulting report contains more than 0 rows.

Comment: Unnecessary data for report is not acceptable. So I can't change the query.